# conditional statement specifying css property

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is most likely very easy but i'm struggling

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function(){
var wH = $(window).height();
var wW = $(window).width();
var hwH = (wH) / 2;
// ---- slide size w+h ----
  $('.slide').css({'height': (wH) +'px', 'width': (wW) +'px'});
  $('#features') .css({'height': (wH+hwH) + 'px'});

// ---- size/min-size for featureItem div's ----
  $('.featureItem') .css({'height': (wH * 1.5) / 5 - 17 +'px'});

});// end resize.function
```

i would like to add a conditional statement for #features along the lines of

```
if$(wH+hwH < 735) {
    $('#features').css({'height': 735 +'px'});
    }
  else {
    $('#features').css({'height': (wH+hwH) + 'px'});
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a jquery selector in your `if` statement?

Comment: Mat, consider using more meaningful variable names. Instead of focusing mental energy on solving the problem, you're forcing us (and you) to have to expend mental energy on learning your encoded language ;) Not only will it help us, but it will help you too. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not a CSS expert, but would this be better accomplished with CSS or would that not work in this case?

Comment: `if$(wH+hwH < 735)` Does not seem right to me.

Comment: @jmort253 setting css min-height is over-ridden by the jquery statement - I tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work? You had a `$` in your if statement and I don't think you have the correct syntax for the `.css()` function. `.height()` might be easier.

```
if(wH+hwH < 735) {
  $('#features').height(735);
}
else {
  $('#features').height(wH+hwH);
}
```

Comment: @mkprogramming, I don't think there is any problem with the `.css()` in his code...

Comment: the $ was the problem  but i further condensed it down to  
`$("#features").height((wH+hwH < 750) ? 750 : wH+hwH);`

Answer (score 3):

Changing

```
if$(wH+hwH < 735)
```

to

```
if (wH+hwH < 735)
```

should do the trick...  if that is what you're asking?